# Is there a proof that logarithm whose anti-logarithm is not a natural power of the base is not a rational number?

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

To write it simplier (at least for me):

Is there a proof that

$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{N}_+\backslash{\{1\}},b>a, \text{a is prime}, \forall k\in\mathbb{N}, b \neq a^k: \\
\log_a b\notin \mathbb{Q}$

so for example (that this question arose from)

Is $\log_2 b$ a rational number only when b ($b\in\mathbb{N}_+$) is a natural power of 2?

Comment: $\log_2 b\in\mathbb{Q}$ exactly if $2^{p/q}=b$ for $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $\log_2(\sqrt{2})=\frac{1}{2}$ but $\sqrt{2}\neq 2^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Just a modified example, so $b\in \mathbb N$, let $a=4$, $b=2$.

Comment: sorry, I will modify it in a second, not what I meant, added that b>a

Comment: @podiki I don't quite see how is that a proof

Comment: @Inquisitor it was a counterexample until you changed the problem. :) now consider $\log_4(8) = 3/2\in\mathbb{Q}$ but $8\neq 4^k$ for any natural number $k$.

Comment: @podiki I hope I made the final change in the problem now :) but really I mostly care for log(2,b) proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll prove the final version by contrapositive. Suppose that $\log_a(b)\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then there exists $q,p\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(q,p)=1$ and

$$a^{p/q} = b.$$

Since $b > a > 1$ we can require that $p > q > 0$. Now raise both sides to the $q$ to obtain

$$a^p = b^q.$$

Since $a$ is prime the left hand side is the prime factorization of $a^p$ and so the prime factorization of the right hand side must also only contain powers of $a$ which means $b=a^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Inquisitor if you are happy with the answer, you should consider accepting it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: didn't know how to do that on mobile, checked it now